# Studio R giving error about "unused arguments" when plotting ROC-curves

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

The code below should display a roc curve for 28-day mortality using a clinical scores (based on organ dysfunction). The code worked perfectly some months ago, now it yields error:

```
"Error in roc(y1, x, plot = TRUE, legacy.axes = TRUE, lwd = 4, add = TRUE,  : 
  unused arguments (plot = TRUE, legacy.axes = TRUE, lwd = 4, add = TRUE, col = "darkred").
```

```
  y1 <- as.integer(E_SOFA_StudyPop$`Dead within 28 d (1/0)`) #

  x <- as.integer(E_SOFA_StudyPop$`3h total SOFA`)

  #28 -d mortality
  par(pty= "s")
  roc.a = roc(y1, x, plot=TRUE, legacy.axes=TRUE, lwd=4, add=TRUE,  col="darkred")
```

I have tried:

- installing the `pROC` package again
- Restarted R session
- Tried one argument at a time, but it gives a similar error for all
  arguments that I tried

As I said, this worked without problems some two months ago, thankful for help with this issue.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have you loaded other packages? What does `environment(roc)` return?

Comment: You may have a local function called `roc()` in your workspace, or have another package attached that also has a function with that name.  Use `pROC::roc()` to be sure to get the right one.

Answer (score 1):

This is [covered by the pROC FAQ](https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-asked-questions#the-functions-are-giving-me-weird-error-messages-i-dont-understand):

> Several packages on CRAN provide alternative `roc` or `auc` functions. These packages can interfere with pROC, especially if they are loaded later in the session (and hence appear earlier in the search path).
>
> For instance, here are a few messages you may see if you have the `AUC` package loaded:
>
> ```
> Not enough distinct predictions to compute area under the ROC curve.
>
> Error in roc(outcome ~ ndka, data = aSAH) : unused argument (data = aSAH)
> ```
>
> If that happens, you should unload the package by typing `detach("package:AUC")`.  To find out where the function is coming from, simply type its name on the R prompt:
>
> ```
> > roc
> function (predictions, labels)
> {
> [function code]
> }
> <bytecode: 0x7fdb71d32ed0>
> <environment: namespace:AUC>
> ```
>
> The line at the bottom indicates that the function comes from the AUC package.
>
> In addition, you may have defined a `roc` function yourself. In this case, `rm(roc)` will solve the problem.
>
> Alternatively you can refer to the pROC version of the function specifically through their namespace:
>
> ```
> pROC::auc(pROC::roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$ndka))
> ```

The FAQ carries on by providing a list of possibly conflicting packages.